# How do I obtain the -true- QR decomposition of a sparse matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, numeric

I have a simple question: say I have a sparse matrix A in R. If I code

```
QR<-qr(A)
Q<-qr.Q(QR)
R<-qr.R(QR)
```

I do not obtain the actual QR decomposition of A, but rather the matrices are such that PAP_=QR
where P and P_ are some permutation matrices (that are given).
In most instances this is probably not an issue, but for my purposes I believe that I absolutely need the 'real' matrices Q and R such that A=QR, with R being upper triangular. As far as I'm aware, this is not available for sparse matrices? At the moment, I am considering converting my matrices to dense matrices, and then applying the qr() function (because for dense matrices, there appear to be no such permutations); however, that seems a bit stupid. I suppose hand-coding a QR factorization is far too complex, no?
Can anyone help with this issue?

P.S. I'm new to stack overflow, I'm usually in the math forums; can I not write in Latex here?

Edit: I should mention that the above applies to the qr decomposition in the matrix package. Apparently, I can use the base qr function, but numerically this seems to not be very nice. (It may be my best option though?)

Comment: No, unfortunately latex doesn't work directly here.

Comment: Try the **EigenR** package. However not sure it works for a sparse matrix.

Comment: I checked. Doesn't work for sparse matrices, sorry.

Comment: Looking at `?Matrix::qr`, does `qrR(qr(X), backpermute = TRUE)` do what you need ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker unless I'm mistaken, 'qrR(qr(X),backpermute=TRUE)' returns RP_^{-1}, using the notation from my question. So no, it doesn't return the true R matrix, it doesn't even return a triangular matrix, in general...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `qr` method for class `dgCMatrix` factorizes an `m`-by-`n` matrix `A` (with `m >= n`) as:

```
P1 * A * P2 = Q * R    <==>    A = P1' * Q * R * P2'
```

where `P1` and `P2` are permutation matrices.  At C level, there is an option to disable column pivoting, so that `P2` is an identity matrix.  Then you have `A = Q~ * R`, where `Q~ = P1' * Q` is orthogonal (because `P1` and `Q` are orthogonal), and you would obtain `Q~` with `qr.Q` and `R` with `qr.R`.

Unfortunately, the option is not exposed at R level in the current **Matrix** version 1.5-4.  To disable column pivoting from R, you must call the C code directly (which outside of this example I strongly discourage):

```r
library(Matrix)
set.seed(1)
x <- rsparsematrix(10L, 10L, 0.5)
stopifnot(is(x, "dgCMatrix"), validObject(x),
          packageVersion("Matrix") == "1.5-4")

qr.x <- qr(x)
all.equal(as(qr.Q(qr.x) %*% qr.R(qr.x), "matrix"), as(x, "matrix"))
## [1] "Mean relative difference: 1.059398"

qr.x <- .Call(Matrix:::dgCMatrix_QR, x, 0L, FALSE)
all.equal(as(qr.Q(qr.x) %*% qr.R(qr.x), "matrix"), as(x, "matrix"))
## [1] TRUE
```

It so happens that I've spent quite a bit of time this past month refactoring the factorization code in **Matrix**.  In **Matrix** 1.6-0 (not yet released), you *will* have the option to disable column pivoting, with `qr(x, order = 0L)`.

A side effect is that the documentation for all matrix factorization classes and methods will be very much improved.  So, people can look forward to that ...

Comment: Great information to have! I will try out this method later, although base::qr actually might be enough for me, and for now I don't want to meddle with something a bit more complicated before finishing my code. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can enforce your R environment to load `base::qr` (otherwise, `Matrix::qr` will override), and then you can process it with an ordinary matrix rather than a sparse matrix

Example

```
> library(Matrix)

> set.seed(1)

> (x <- rsparsematrix(7L, 5L, 0.5))
7 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"

[1,] -0.62  .     -0.480 -2.000 .
[2,]  .    -1.500  .     -2.200 .
[3,]  .     0.075  .     -0.056 0.62
[4,]  0.39  1.100 -0.016  .     .
[5,]  .     .      0.820  0.780 .
[6,]  .     .      .      0.940 0.59
[7,] -0.16 -0.045  0.920  .     .

> QR <- base::qr(x)

> Q <- qr.Q(QR)

> R <- qr.R(QR)

> X <- qr.X(QR)

> all.equal(Q %*% R, X)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is currently what I am doing. It's probably the best solution? I guess the only downside is that there seem to be more small numerical errors than with matrix::qr, which in my case often gave the exact coefficients for Q%*%R. I'm guessing all.equal() has a slight tolerance for numerical error? (Not very used to R).